# PHP, PHPMailer: Can't get example code for PHPMailer to work

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to get php mailer to work. I'm getting an error but couldn't find any info from google on it.

```
$mail = new phpmailer;

$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->From = "from@email.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
$mail->AddAddress("user@theirsite.com", "User");
//$mail->AddAddress("ellen@site.com");   // name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@site.com", "Information");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;    // set word wrap
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\js-bak.sql");  // add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");

$mail->IsHTML(true);    // set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body = "This is the message body";
$mail->Send(); // send message
```

The code above is what I'm using but when I try to run it I get the following in my browser...

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /the/full/path/to/phpmailer.inc.php on line 271
```

Here is the line it's referring to...

```
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->$Encoding);
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `$this->Encoding`? I don't think `Encoding` is a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Encoding` is not a variable: `$this->Encoding`

Comment: Crazy, well I downloaded it from their site, I guess they messed up because I haven't edited that file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

There's an error on line 271 in file phpmailer.inc.php

The line is :

```
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->$Encoding);
```

Change it for :

```
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->Encoding);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want `$this->$Encoding`? I think you want `$this->Encoding` (note the lack of $ on Encoding).

Comment: Thanks for the help didn't notice it and I hadn't edited their file so I didn't really check it. Definitely learned something today :)