# PHPMailer doesn`t work with AddAddress property set

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a contact form using phpMailer and I get in firebug this:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - path/process.php
uncaught exception: [object Object]
```

each time I'm trying to run the code below.
Please note that the error is not shown anymore if I remove `$mail->AddAddress` line, that's why I suspect this line to be the cause.
Instead a new error is displayed: `You must provide at least one recipient email address` when I remove it.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['firstName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
require("phpmailer.inc.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->Subject = "subject ";
$mail->Body = "From $name with email: $email";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->AddAddress('my_address@gmail.com','my name');
$mail->Send();
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide the php error, the network error is too generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite it to:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['firstName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
require 'phpmailer.inc.php';
try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsMail();
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->Subject = "subject ";
    $mail->Body = "From $name with email: $email";
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->AddAddress('my_address@gmail.com','my name');
    $mail->Send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and you will catch the error

Comment: I simply don't get any exception when running with try/catch, but only a blank page..and  when running via ajax the form is not submitted and the same error shown in firebug. Is there something that I'm missing in order to be able to see a pretty error message? I'm a designer not programmer, that's why I'm a little confused.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. It is the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653259/php-phpmailer-cant-get-example-code-for-phpmailer-to-work Thanks!